# curl: (3) <url> malformed issue in my shell script

Tags: shell, jenkins, curl, curly-braces

Here is my script trying to automate JIRA task using shell script

```
#!/bin/bash

jiraURL="http://cde-jira.com/rest/api/latest/issue/"
#input=JiraNames.txt
input=testJira.txt
Date=$(date)

while IFS=: read -r WORD1 WORD2; 
do     
              if [[ "${folder}" = $WORD1 ]]; then
              echo "${instance}"-"$folder" JIRA found
              echo $WORD2
              jiraURL="${jiraURL}${WORD2}"
              echo "${jiraURL}"
              fi
done < "${input}"

echo Updating "${instance}"-"${folder}" comment section on $Date

curl -sf -D- -u "${ADMIN_USER}":"${ADMIN_PWD}" -X PUT -d "{\"update\": {\"comment\": [{\"add\": {\"body\": \""${instance}"-"${folder}" migration has been initiated on $Date\"}}]}}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "${jiraURL}"



echo Updating "${instance}"-"${folder}" status to In Progress

curl -sf -D- -u "${ADMIN_USER}":"${ADMIN_PWD}" -X PUT -d "{\"update\": {\"comment\": [{\"add\": {\"body\": \""${instance}"-"${folder}" folder migration is in progress...\"}}]}}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "${jiraURL}"

jiraTransitionURL="${jiraURL}/transitions"

curl -sf -D- -u "${ADMIN_USER}":"${ADMIN_PWD}" -X POST --data '{"transition": { "id": "11" } }' -H "Content-Type: application/json" "${jiraTransitionURL}"


echo Updating "${instance}"-"${folder}" status to Under Review

curl -sf -D- -u "${ADMIN_USER}":"${ADMIN_PWD}" -X PUT -d "{\"update\": {\"comment\": [{\"add\": {\"body\": \""${instance}"-"${folder}" folder migration has been completed successfully!\"}}]}}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "${jiraURL}"

curl -sf -D- -u "${ADMIN_USER}":"${ADMIN_PWD}" -X POST --data '{"transition": { "id": "21" } }' -H "Content-Type: application/json" "${jiraTransitionURL}"

curl -sf -D- -u "${ADMIN_USER}":"${ADMIN_PWD}" -X PUT -d "{\"update\": {\"comment\": [{\"add\": {\"body\": \"The legacy folder "${instance}"-"${folder}" will be ACTIVE for three weeks from now and will be moved to READ ONLY MODE on $(date -d +"21 days")\"}}]}}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" "${jiraURL}"


echo Update DueDate of Jira !

DueDate=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d" -d "+21 days")

echo $DueDate

curl -sf -u "${ADMIN_USER}":"${ADMIN_PWD}" -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" "${jiraURL}" -d '{"update": { "duedate": [ {"set": "2020-06-10"} ] } }' -X PUT –sS
```

Error:

```
curl: (3) <url> malformed
```

Can someone help where do i did mistake? It seems my code is correct with all braces even it is throwing error. Please help me on this issue

Comment: Try running `bash -x yourscript.sh` and check how the `$jiraURL` value is being treated by the script.

Comment: I think it's working after adding it. Can you please tell the reason why the failure occurs ?

Comment: The `-x` just makes the output verbose when running your script, so it should not change anything on it. There is no reason to think that flag just changed something on how your script works.